# npm and other modules commands not working

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

- **Note:** I am on Windows 10 64 bit running the latest LTS Node build.

It all started when I tried running the command `npm i -g create-react-app` and I get a message saying that npm is not a command.

[image: npm not a command]

I checked my **PATH** and I believe I have the proper directories in there.

[image: path]

I navigated to the directory of npm and tried running the command again, but it still didn't work. I found that the command `npm.cmd` worked in any directory. So tried running `npm.cmd i -g create-react-app` and that worked! I also had to use the the command `create-react-app.cmd my-app`, instead of `create-react-app my-app`. I thought I was set and I could just use those `.cmd` commands for the things I needed to do; however, when I tried to run the command `create-react-app.cmd my-app` and got this as a result:

[image]

I have looked in the file that is ran when using this command `create-react-app.cmd my-app` and there is no sign of `npm` being called. Turns out Node is being called in that file with the command below. I know this because when I run it by itself and I get the same output to the console seen in the previous image.

`"node"  "C:\Users\Allen\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js" my-app` 
it was called in the `create-react-app.cmd` file like this `"%_prog%"  "%dp0%\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js" %*`

I am at a loss. I could continue down this rabbit hole and try and find the node file that is calling npm and change it to npm.cmd but I would rather find a way to get the npm and create-react-app commands working as they are suppose to. At the very least I can just spin up a VM and work in that. It is just annoying that I can't get Node to work properly for me.

Comment: type `set` in a command prompt to check what PATHEXT is set to.  I have `PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`  I suspect somehow .CMD is not in yours.

Comment: Reference: https://superuser.com/questions/1027078/what-is-the-default-value-of-the-pathext-environment-variable-for-windows

Comment: I only had ```.EXE;.PY,``` in my PATHEXT. After adding those extensions I typed the command ```npm -v``` and got 

```The system cannot find the path specified.

6.14.4```

Seems like I get the message ```The system cannot find the path specified.``` then the command executes are expected

It's odd because other commands like ```code``` work with out displaying that first message.

Comment: That's interesting, but despite the extra message, is everything working now?  BTW in a cmd shell, try the command `where npm`.  I get `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm` followed by `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd`.  The first is actually a bourne script so it's ignored and the `npm.cmd` file is invoked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `npx create-react-app my-app` this will help you create react projects.

Also check the documentation : https://reactjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

First check that you have `npm` installed on your machine and the version. You can just type `npm version`. Since npm version 5.2.0 npx is pre-bundled with npm, which is a CLI tool whose purpose is to make it easy to install and manage dependencies hosted in the npm registry. So try using `npx create-react-app app-name`. You can confirm that you are able to use npx by running `which npx`. If it is not available then you can install it by running `npm install -g npx`.